# Is it "group axiom" or "group definition"?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Some text books of group theory use "group definitions" when introducing *group*, and some other text books use "group axioms". But it is obvious that terms "definition" and "axiom" are different. Which one is more relevant?

Comment: Axioms are definitions.

Comment: @Gina No. Axiom has a property of definition but those are different. Axioms are premise for true propositions. And definition is an explanation of notions, or concepts. Those are not in equal relation.

Comment: No, in modern mathematics, axioms are pretty much the same thing as definitions. Axioms are the way we formalize an abstract notion.

Comment: Just explain it like me above. Not just throwing a result -> will not believe without any relevant reasons.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You question is based on the premise "terms definition and axiom are different.", but you should - as the one asking the question - be open to the possibility that this is a false premise and that in fact the two terms are no more different than a falcon is different from a kestrel.

Comment: You said "it is obvious that terms "definition" and "axiom" are different". Isn't this exactly an example of what you called "just throwing a result"? Can you explain what is your reason for believing that "definition" and "axiom" are different?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Of course you can't understand as you just removed and filtered the point of my comment. I said, which you can read, that an Axiom is a premise "for true propositions", and definition is an "explanation of notions, or concepts". We can premise "terms" of the notions to demonstrate.

Comment: @Gina There was a reason. I already *explained* about the notions for "Axiom" and "Definition", which are different notions.

Comment: I did not "remove and filter" anything from any comment of yours. But I won't bother trying to explain something to someone that doesn't want to hear it. If you treat people who comment on your question like that, I'm afraid how you'll react when someone posts an answer. (Be nice to people who are helping you for no actual return, it's a good thing.)

Comment: These are the axioms that define a group. Calling an axiom a premise "for true propositions" harks back to the days when Euclidean geometry was thought to be the only possible geometry.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am very confused. I am just asking my questions and insisting my opinions, did not ignoring others opinions. And I am very disappointed about peoples who behave quite emotional.

Comment: I will just post this: "Susan Haak (1978) wrote, "A set of axioms is sometimes said to give an implicit definition of its primitive terms."" from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_notion. Also "We must simply be prepared to use labels like "line" and "parallel" with greater flexibility" from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom.

Comment: Note that you could also consider what are often known as the "Peano Postulates" - people use different words for the same ideas.

Comment: At one stage in mathematics it seemed important to find a minimal set of properties which defined a mathematical object, or which expressed why mathematical structures which intuitively "looked the same" were in fact the same. There might be a sense in which axioms were then more associated with minimal properties. Definitions which are not minimal carry redundancies and it may be necessary to prove they are consistent.

Comment: Have you ever read Euclid's Elements? I was surprised how much mathematical content was introduced in the definitions.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the various misunderstandings that are going on in this comment thread are primarily based on disagreements about history and linguistics, not disagreements about mathematics. In the context of the OP's question, the words "axiom" and "definition" are terms of ordinary language. Ordinary language evolves. At different times, and in different contexts, the words "axiom" and "definition" can be used in different manners.

Comment: The OP is perfectly free to point out that many modern writers do not use these words in a manner that distinguishes their meaning. And the commentators are also perfectly free to point out that many modern writers do not use these words in a manner that distinguishes their meaning. No need to fight about it.